# Cannot Turn on Timed publishing mode in Google Play Console

Tags: android, publish, google-play-console

I want to update app in Google Play Console as Timed publishing mode. But I cannot turn it on. Cannot find Time Publishing switch. Any idea about this?

[My Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uphjI.png)

Comment: if your app have some serious runtime permissions you need to attach a privacy policy for publishing your app

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, I already attached the privacy policy. The problem is  cannot see Time Publishing switcher. So I cannot turn it on

Comment: click on Store presence on the left side and check, also attach that screenshot

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, here is screenshot
https://ibb.co/nM8t9Qx

Answer (score 7):

In the new Google console the wording has changed.

Look for "Publishing overview" in the left side menu, then find the "Managed publishing status" and press "Manage" button.

[image]

You will be prompted with a popup that allows to turn the Managed publishing on.

Comment: This is correct answer as of 10-2020. Anybody have complete step to step guide for time publishing?

Comment: Note that this "Managed publishing status" section is only available once you've submitted a production release for review.

Answer (score 5):

Timed Publishing switch will also not appear if you have any version already under review (including in internal tracks).

To confirm a review is in progress you can check the status at the main Dashboard:
[image]

Once review completes, you'll find the switch at the bottom of the "Store Listing" page under Store presence in left menu.

It's really at the bottom after all fields, beside the save button.

Answer (score 2):

We are having the same issue -- the option to enable isn't where it should be. We reached out to the Google Play Dev Ops team and they notified us that it's a known problem on their side. They are aware and working on it. Cheers.

Comment: you should add this as a comment to the question, not asnwer as it does not solve the query of OP.

Answer (score 0):

For reference use the below link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en

1. First go to the `Publish an app update`.
2. Then click the `Publish with timed publishing`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get content rating and other certifications first.
Also set the privacy policy url and upload your first APK.
Then only timely publishing menu will get enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Adding step by step guide on timely publishing in new google console

1. Navigate to your App's Dashboard and select **Publishing overview** from left side menu.
2. Check **Managed publishing status**. It should be **Managed publishing on** if not then click manage and opt for Managed publishing on.
3. Track google's approval
4. After google's approval, go to **Publishing overview** and check publish button corresponding your app underneath **Changes in review**.
5. Publish it